# Identity Server 4 External IDP Signout Tidyup

Tags: single-sign-on, openid, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have Identity Server 4 running ok performing local authentication for an MVC app working fine. I needed to add support for an external IDP too so I followed the instructions in the documentation and based it on the quickstart code. So its currently configured to use the demo IDP at https://demo.identityserver.io as an external IDP and works fine for login - the user gets redirected to the external IDP for entering their details, my auth server gets back an id_token with user id (subject) which I match to a user in our own user repository. Our auth server then continues the login as per normal issuing its own tokens etc. - so all fine so far.

The problem I have is Sign-Out from the external IDP - if a user signs out from the demo.identityservier.io IDP directly, I need to ensure this filters back to clear up the stored authentication cookies thus requiring the user to sign in again if they attempt to access a protected page in the app.

This works ok if the user logs out of our own ID Server (i.e. the logout page presented by the ID Server has built-in iframes that ensure the MVC app gets tidied up). For the external IDP I would expect a similar thing, but cant see anything.

Here's the startup config registering the external IDP within our local IDP startup.

```
        .AddOpenIdConnect("Ext_oidc", "Ext OpenID Connect", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
            options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io/";
            options.ClientId = "implicit";
            options.ResponseType = "id_token";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            };
        });
```

Any suggestions would be greatfully received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you provided an end session endpoint URL to the external IDP? If it's defined I'd expect it to be called as part of the explicit sign out process on the external IDP.

Comment: The code snippet in the original post is all I have added so far, but looking in debug the Authentication options also has defaults set for RemoteSignOutPath and SignedOutCallbackPath which are /signout-oidc and /signout-callback-oidc respectively.

Reading the Identity Server 4 documentation on federated sign-out it would seem to suggest its all just handled out of the box.
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout_federated.html

Comment: The remote IDP's client config would still need to know about the end session endpoint of your client IDP though - without that it can't make the call.

Comment: Ah you're right @mackie, and the demo idsrv wont know that hence why I get nothing back. You pointed me in the right direction.
I hosted a second copy of my own id server (B) and configured a client for ID server (A) to use as the external IDP.

Then adding this additional info to the OIDC setup in ID server (A)
                    `options.CallbackPath = "/signin-Ext_oidc";
                    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-Ext_oidc";
                    options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signoutExt_oidc";`
It then worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

In your MVC app use below code in an action an call it to sign out and clear app cookie and ID Server cookies.

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes()
            .Select(o => o.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
```

Comment: Its an external IDP - I dont have access to the code!
Also, I'm testing against the official test identity server 4 so I would have assumed the creators have already implemented it correctly?

Comment: You need to implement sing-out functionality in your MVC application to sign-out from both external IDP and your MVC app, check updated answer.

Comment: I already have a front channel logout url defined in the Client configuration - if I login just using our local IDP and then logout from identity server, then the MVC app callback is called ok and the session correctly cleared up.

Similarly, if I initiate logout via the MVC App itself, then both the session and IDP are logged out.

The problem occurs when the external IDP is involved - if I signed our there first, then both the local IDP and MVC app are left high and dry with no notifications.